# What hosting should I choose so that video streaming could be possible?

Tags: video, hosting, streaming

What hosting should I choose so that video streaming could be possible?

Comment: What kind of video streaming?  will you be developing the streaming software yourself?  how much traffic do you expect?  what quality video will you be streaming?  I think your question is too vauge to answer properly right now.

Comment: too many questions. post your questions on your own.

Answer (score 0):

A streaming server like Flash Media Server would be required for proper streaming video which may make finding a hosting provider difficult. Have you thought about using progressive download instead? This offers quite a few advantages and means you could use something like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) as a cheaper more scalable alternative to hosting your own videos.